# Google App Script: getActiveSheet() not working.

Tags: google-apps-script

So, first of all, this used to work perfectly, up until about a week or so ago. However, now it has stopped working and gives the following error.

Error encountered: Unknown sheet name

Any ideas. Here is the fragment of code being called.

```
var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [an issue on this on the issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1476&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner), please star it to keep track of its evolution. If your case is different (not related to Ui), then you can start a new one.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a workaround at all? It's a bit of a blocker for an application we're developing.

Comment: I'm afraid there is nothing to do but to wait they solve this. I'm also in a big trouble because of that :-)   I've tried every possible alternative without success.

Comment: Ah ok. That's annoying. I also saw your solution to make a window draggable. It's a pity the title can not be styled though! Thanks for that solution!

Comment: Yesssssss ;-) that's great news ! thank for letting us know ;-)